# Streaming tweets with Hosebird

Tags: twitter, streaming

I'm trying to get a stream of public tweets using Hosebird (https://github.com/twitter/hbc), which I'm completely new to.  I tried using their 'Quickstart' example, just to get an idea of what the streaming is like, so I copied the example code.  The only changes I made were getting rid of the 'followings' variable, and filling in the proper OAuth information.

After connecting using `hosebirdClient.connect()`, I added this code in an attempt to print one tweet:

```
String msg = null;
   try {
      msg = msgQueue.take();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
System.out.println(msg);
```

The code is free of errors, but then stays on the line `String msg = msgQueue.take()` forever, instead of producing a tweet.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, and I think the issue might involve trying to use/compile Maven in Eclipse, which I've never done before.  I'm trying to look into this, but any information would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, so hopefully I can help anyone else who has this issue in the future.  My code was correct, but I had to use Maven instead of making a normal Java project.  In Maven, I needed to install the exec plugin by adding this to the POM file:

`<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>Test.Twitter2.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>`

After that, running the program as a Maven build with the goal of exec:java worked perfectly.